# Edit product via POST /products API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, products, async

I’ve enabled single-store mode and created a new product using the `async/bulk/V1/products` functionality `(\Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Model\MassSchedule)`. Initially, all attributes of this product are saved under `store_id = 0 (admin store)`. When editing the product via the admin panel, the attribute values are appropriately updated in the respective tables (e.g., varchar) for the correct store `(store_id = 0)`.

However, an issue arises when attempting to restore the product via `async/bulk/V1/products.` Instead of updating the existing record in the varchar table, a new record gets created with `store_id = 1`, despite setting `store_id=0` in the storeManager before publishing to the queue.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue? I am looking for a solution where either the initial save is directly under `store_id = 1`, or the edited product’s attributes are saved under `store_id = 0` when using the API.